# How to force Google CSE to search just uploaded PDF file

Tags: pdf, search

I am using free Google custom search engine in my website to search mostly PDF and HTML files. It works pretty much well, however it doesn't search PDF file just uploaded. Is it due to that Google bot needs sometime to crawl? Is there anyway we can allow to search instantly?

The website is : http://benchmarkinc.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to automatically index newly uploaded PDFs or are you able to manually add those PDFs to the CSE after they've been uploaded?

You can add specific files to your index from the CSE control panel -> Admin - Indexing tab and then add the URLs for the PDFs you want Google to index.
Apparently, it takes up to 24 hours for Google to index the PDF.